# Philosophy of Culture : is everything that is social also cultural? ( " social structure"/ " culture" controversy)

Tags: philosophy-of-social-sciences

My question could be understood as pointing towards natural explanations of social phenomena; this is however an aspect of the question I'd prefer to leave out here.

My question could be reworded as follows: If one admits ( for the sake of the question I am asking here) that human social phenomena are " sui generis" and distinct from natural phenomena ( and particularly biological phenomena), is it legitimate to comprehend all these social phenomena under the concept of " culture" or is there a part of social phenomena that are not " cultural".

---

Context: philosophical reflection on the concept of culture ( with an aim at taking into account some results of cultural anthropology)

The original concept of culture in anthropology  is Tylor's : "“Culture… is that complex whole which includes knowledge, beliefs, arts, morals, law, customs, and any other capabilities and habits acquired by [a human] as a member of society.”

This definition seems to encompass all social phenomena.

This tendency is confirmed by a standard definition of " culture" given by ralph Linton in The Study Of Man : culture is " social heredity".

However, this tendency to embrace all social phenomena in culture seems to have been resisted by some social scientists.

Apparently, there has been a controversy between sociologically oriented thinkers stressing the importance of " social structure" as opposed to or distinguished  from  culture.

Please, could anyone give some *basic* explanations regarding this controversy (what is at stake with it and maybe its origin)?

Reference : The concept of Culture by Milton Singer , Cengage, at Encyclopedia.com

https://www.encyclopedia.com/social-sciences-and-law/anthropology-and-archaeology/anthropology-terms-and-concepts/culture#A

Comment: The title does not match the question, you should switch "social" and "cultural" in it. Much of what is social is biological, as ants and bees demonstrate, see [sociobiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociobiology).

Comment: @Conifold. - Question edited in order to take your remark into account.

Comment: See [What is Culture ?](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/culture-cogsci/#WhaCul)

Comment: @MauroAllegranza-Thanks for this link to SEP.

Comment: I do not think that the two terms are equal; society is made of individuals and their relations : familiar, legal, economical **and** cultural. It is hard to believe that we may have "social structures" without some cultural relations/products, but I think that we cannot equate the two.

Comment: I think that we can think the difference between society and culture through a linguistic example : society is made of the (human) *speakers* while society is the *speech* (the text).

Comment: Obviously, there is no speech without speakers, and speakers are not speakers if they do not speak, i.e. if they do not produce texts...

Comment: Society = a group of people who live and work together. Culture = the way of life is followed by the group (society).

Comment: I *suspect* that this question might see better answers from the Academia SE, as my suspicion is that the roots of this controversy lies within that sphere.  But I might be wrong.

Comment: @Roger. What is academia SE devoted to?

Comment: Academia SE covers academic institutions such as universities and would be suited for questions around why and how departments have turf wars over certain subjects.

Comment: This question does not deserve -2.  I have noticed weird voting on other questions too lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concepts 'culture' and 'social structure' have their roots in two separate social science disciplines. They may overlap in many dimensions — natural enough, since they both study the same thing — but their *intentions* are different, and they are not a perfect match.

'Culture' comes from anthropology, and was meant to describe the *continuity* of social groups: i.e., how and why a social group replicates behaviors across generations. In that sense it tends to focus (as the definition you gave notes) on *collective habits* that persist across generations. For that reason, anthropology sometimes has a difficult time talking about social change: the manner in which collective habits are challenged, broken down, or altered over time.

'Social structure,' by contrast, comes from sociology, and is meant to describe the *functional relationships* between different people in a society. The idea here is that there are certain collective tasks that need to be performed by someone, and that these tasks are usually consigned to specific people whose social role is to fulfill them. Sociology does a better job of accounting for social changes: e.g., a sociologist can talk about the industrial revolution, and how the new demand for the role of 'factory worker' drew people out of rural agricultural peasantry into the urban proletariat. But sociology doesn't necessarily deal well with social continuity, where non-pragmatic considerations like 'tradition' can come into play.

So for example, an anthropologist will look at an institution like *marriage* as part of a cultural heritage, filled with rites and symbolisms passed down through history. A sociologist will look at the same institution as a way of organizing certain divisions of labor, and of transmitting and controlling property across time. Neither perspective is wrong, and neither is complete; they are complementary ways of looking at the issue.

Comment: This sheds light on what is at stake in the controversy Milton Singer refers to in his article. Thanks.